# How to select elements by part of their name in XSL/XPath?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, transform

How do I use apply-templates to select only those elements by name (not value) that end with a specific pattern? Assume the following xml...

```
<report>
  <report_item>
    <report_created_on/>
    <report_cross_ref/>
    <monthly_adj/>
    <quarterly_adj/>
    <ytd_adj/>
  </report_item>
  <report_item>
   ....
  </report_item>
</report>
```

I want to use `<xsl:apply-templates>` on all instances of `<report_item>` where descendant elements end with 'adj`, so, in this case, only monthly_adj, quaterly_adj, and ytd_adj would be selected and applied with the template.

```
<xsl:template match="report">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="report_item/(elements ending with 'adj')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that regular expression syntax is available in this context, even in XSLT 2.0.  But you don't need it in this case.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="report_item/*[ends-with(name(), 'adj')]"/>
```

`*` matches any node

`[pred]` performs a node test against the selector (in this case `*`) (where `pred` is a predicate evaluated in the context of the selected node)

`name()` returns the element's tag name (should be equivalent to `local-name` for this purpose).

`ends-with()` is a built-in XPath string function.

Comment: NEW STACKOVERFLOW WORLD RECORD....Fastest Answer Ever, LOL, you're right, not regex, just simple `ends with` was enough, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)  I've updated the title to better match the question.

Comment: Note that ends-with is _not_ available in xslt **1.0**. See [use ends with in XSLT v1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848780/use-ends-with-in-xslt-v1-0) for a 1.0 work-around.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly neater solution (XSLT 2.0+ only):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="report_item/*[matches(name(),'adj$')]"/>
```

Here is a self-test to prove it works. (Tested on Saxon).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
 <xsl:variable name="report-data">
  <report>
   <report_item>
     <report_created_on/>
     <report_cross_ref/>
     <monthly_adj>Jan</monthly_adj>
     <quarterly_adj>Q1</quarterly_adj>
     <ytd_adj>2012</ytd_adj>
   </report_item>
  </report>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
  <reports-ending-with-adj>
   <xsl:element name="using-regex">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$report-data//report_item/*[fn:matches(name(),'adj$')]"/> 
   </xsl:element>
   <xsl:element name="using-ends-with-function">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$report-data//report_item/*[fn:ends-with(name(), 'adj')]"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </reports-ending-with-adj>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `match` worked for me. But I have an issue: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp5/3 (I would like the order of `mOrder` to say which `li` I would like to display first, second, third...) Thank you.

Comment: Or something like this: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp5/4 (I am looking to display the parent LI and sub LI but it is multiplying for each iteration and duplicating. The empty LI I would like to not show and only show if it has a text.) Thanks for the help

Comment: Post a question, and it will be answered.