# echo selected data in php from xml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need to parse the linked XML. How would I select a dynamic tag (in this case _0F2E09D773BD4A4B9B9F74D7A8B99A51) and echo damagedealt for Blood_Wolf89?

[Pastebin to xml data](http://pastebin.com/fg2bK6GY)

Comment: SimpleXML will be your friend in this case.  http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: 1) Thank you, I have been looking at SimpleXML. I am having issues figuring out how to get the data from the dynamic tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one line:

```
echo simplexml_load_file('test.xml')->xpath("//*[@playername='Blood_Wolf89'][ancestor::_0F2E09D773BD4A4B9B9F74D7A8B99A51]")[0]['damagedealt'];
```

But this require known tag name of ancestor. Because without ancestor you have many Blood_Wolf89 results.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sofar I think I am good now. I may need more help in the near future. If I do I will post it here. Again, Thank you!

Comment: Oh I have a question, How would I get the data in _8B00F0222E98407E9637D5573F929B24? For example gamemode="3" or matchtype="pve"

Comment: Questions, questions,questions... This is easy. I think you should look here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! I almost skipped dinner because I am now on a role thanks to you! I have done stuff with json and I thought it would be similar.. Ok Back to work for me! hahaha

Comment: I can not figure out how I would dynamically echo the node name and namespace from this..

  http://pastebin.com/YKeXnDUs

Comment: One more question, is there a way to search for a child while knowing part of the name?

Comment: @Blood_Wolf89 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9267215/3558278