# Search my String in All the HTML tags from HTML page

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Below is my regular expression

```
preg_match_all("/\<p\>(.*)".$_GET['searchString']."(.*)\<\/p\>/i", $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

which will search my string within `<p> </p>` Tags only inside my HTML page.

Can anyone tell me that if i want to search my string in all the HTML element inside my HTML page , what regular expression i should write ?

Thanks in advance.

Below artical will make you understand that what exactly i want to do 
http://www.stratos.me/2009/07/search-feature-on-static-html-sites-the-smart-way/

Comment: This is my similar answer (you can use all of this practice) http://stackoverflow.com/a/40252630/3558278

Comment: @Deep Buddy i want Regex . . . . what should be there instead of this `"/\<p\>(.*)".$_GET['searchString']."(.*)\<\/p\>/i"`    ias i said i need to search my string inside my entire HTML.. dosent matter what the HTML tag is there,. Currently its only searching the text which are written inside <p> tag..

Comment: You do not want regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3558278

Comment: may be @Deep has a point here ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave , Please read the article i have shared, You will understand it better.

Comment: @PunitGajjar yea i have read this one but if u read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 what they are saying, they have a point too .. **You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML**

Comment: @PunitGajjar static pages? good news for you - javascript support xpath (without IE)

Comment: @Deep yeahh i have static pages.. ..

Comment: @Deep  Please join here , http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126888/html-and-regex

Answer (score 0):

How about this way, is this your want?

```
<?php
    $str="<p>test</p><P>test</p><b>test
    </b>";
    $key = "test";
    preg_match_all("#<\s*([a-zA-Z]*)[^>]*>.*?{$key}.*?<\/\s*\\1\s*>#msi",$str,$match);
    if(isset($match[0])) {
       print_r($match[0]);
    }else{
       echo "No match";
    }
#output
Array
(
    [0] => <p>test</p>
    [1] => <P>test</p>
    [2] => <b>test
     </b>
)
```

Comment: Still you dont get me., 
I said  HTML tag dosent matter for me.  searchString should get the result even  its written withing <Div> or <p> or <b> or <i>   any kind of tag..

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $str="<p>test</p><p>asasafs</p><p>xxxxr</p>";
    preg_match_all("#<p>(.*?)<\/p>#",$str,$match);
    if(isset($match[1])) {
       print_r($match[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Parse html with regexp? OMG! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3558278

Comment: @wang , i guess you dont get me . .  Please read my question carefully . Also check the article once ..

Comment: yea .. may be @PunitGajjar wants to get all the strings with having any of html tags .. is it punit ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave ,, Exactly ..... dosent matter what the HTML tag is there,  just my  Seach string should be there inside my HTMl page .

Comment: misundestand , i am sorry @P